# dllhost.exe proccess appears after updating windows

Tags: windows-7, updates, dll

Two days ago I updated my PC to Windows 7 (32 bit) Ultimate and after that whenever i click any file type  dllhost.exe proccess with below processid starts and if i close that, it will start again

```
C:\Windows\system32\DllHost.exe /Processid:{3EB3C877-1F16-487C-9050-104DBCD66683}
```

Before i update this windows, I didn't have this problem and I'm sure this dllhost.exe isn't infected by malware.

I searched for this and found These methods that didn't work for me:

1. rebuild icon cache
2. add dllhost.exe to data execution prevention list
3. Run `sfc /scannow` command

This is a screenshot of dll and other files that this proccess handles:

[image]

I have this problem in my Asus notebook with windows 7 ultimate (64 bit),too and it started after windows update several months ago.

I searched for Processid:{3EB3C877-1F16-487C-9050-104DBCD66683} and it seems it is related to wininet.dll

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The process is probably related to Firefox. see here: http://superuser.com/questions/579715/firefox-spawns-a-dllhost-exe-process-when-downloading-zip-files Firefox uses wininet.dll to provide caching to firefox and other browsers.

Comment: What you describe isn't a problem

Comment: You can always uninstall the update

Comment: Is this an actual problem? Does this running process break anything or is this just an annoyance?

Comment: Your screenshot has also not come through, please post a link to it so that someone can edit it in for you.

Comment: Scanned for Malware lately?

Comment: Thanks all for you help...@Frank Thomas:not only related to firefox and with any multimedia files that i click this proccess runs,even i end task it..i also checked this in safe mode...@Ramhound & Mokubai :many updates have been installed and i don't know which one caused this problem and the problem is just consumption resources of dllhost.exe!sorry,I forgot to post the screenshoot,this link->http://i.solidfiles.net/9e658ecd01.jpg.... @Moab :yes,i scanned dllhost file with virustotal and as i said,i have this problem in another windows 7,too

Comment: Another thing-> After updating this windows,whenever i click a file to open it,some data will be written to below file and my try to delete this file cause this error->this file is open in com surrogate!  C:\Users\Milad\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat

Comment: The thread linked previously isn't just about Firefox, but also IE 10. "com surrogate" is just a generic name for a process that runs code of a COM object but in a separate process context. It's not a problem. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/12/9413816.aspx Is it actually causing a performance problem for you? n.b.: If you insist on knowing the function of every unfamiliar process in the system you're going to spend a lot more time micromanaging your machine than using it for its intended purpose.